# actualizar formulario y logo por ajax y js

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

hola estoy intentando hacer que los datos de un formulario se actualicen por ajax y js
pero tengo problemas con actualizar el logo no se de que manera hacerlo.

codigo java:

```
//actualizar datos empresa
$('#frmEmpresa').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var varchNit        = $('#txtNit').val();
    var strNombreEmp   = $('#txtNombre').val();
    var varchTelEmp   = $('#txtTelEmpresa').val();
    var strEmailEmp   = $('#txtEmailEmpresa').val();
    var strDirEmp     = $('#txtDirEmpresa').val();
    var intIva       = $('#txtIva').val();
    var logo        = $('#foto').val();
    var actual    = $('#logo_actual').val();
    var remove    = $('#logo_remove').val();
    console.log(logo);
    console.log(actual);
    console.log(remove);
    if(varchNit == '' || strNombreEmp == '' || varchTelEmp == '' || strEmailEmp == '' || strDirEmp == '' || intIva == ''){
        $('.alertFormEmpresa').html('<p style="color:red">Todos los campos son obligatorios.</p>');
        //muestra el mensaje
        $('.alertFormEmpresa').slideDown();
        return false;
    }

    $.ajax({
        url : 'ajax.php',
        type: "POST",
        enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
        async :true,
        data: $('#frmEmpresa').serialize(),
        beforeSend: function(){
            $('.alertFormEmpresa').slideUp();
            $('.alertFormEmpresa').html('');
            $('#frmEmpresa input').attr('disabled','disabled');
        },
        success: function(response)
        {
            console.log(response);
            var info = JSON.parse(response);
            if(info.cod == '00'){
                $('.alertFormEmpresa').html('<p style="color: #23922d;">Datos actualizados correctamente</p>');
                $('.alertFormEmpresa').slideDown();
            }else{
                $('.alertFormEmpresa').html('<p style="color:red;">'+info.msg+'</p>');
            }
            $('.alertFormEmpresa').slideDown();
            $('#frmEmpresa input').removeAttr('disabled');
            
           
        },
        error: function(error){

        }

    });
});
```

codigo php :

```
//actualizar datos empresa
    if($_POST['action'] == 'updateDataEmpresa')
    {
        if(empty($_POST['txtNit']) || empty($_POST['txtNombre']) || empty($_POST['txtTelEmpresa']) || empty($_POST['txtEmailEmpresa']) || empty($_POST['txtDirEmpresa']) || empty($_POST['txtIva']) || empty($_POST['logo_actual']) || empty($_POST['logo_remove']))
        {
            $code = '1';
            $msg = "Todos los campos son obligatorios";
        }else{

            $varchNit        = $_POST['txtNit'];
            $strNombreEmp   = $_POST['txtNombre'];
            $varchTelEmp   = $_POST['txtTelEmpresa'];
            $strEmailEmp   = $_POST['txtEmailEmpresa'];
            $strDirEmp     = $_POST['txtDirEmpresa'];
            $intIva       = intval($_POST['txtIva']);

            $imgEmpresa = $_POST['logo_actual'];
            $imgRemove = $_POST['logo_remove'];
            $foto        = $_FILES["foto"];
            $nombre_foto = $foto["name"];
            $type        = $foto["type"];
            $url_temp    = $foto["tmp_name"];

            $upd = '';
            if($nombre_foto != "")
            {
                $destino ="factura/img/";
                $img_nombre = "img_".md5(date('d-m-y H:m:s'));
                $imgEmpresa= $img_nombre.'.jpg';
                $src        = $destino.$imgEmpresa;
            }else{
                if($_POST['logo_actual'] != $_POST['logo_remove']){
                    $imgEmpresa = 'logo.png';
                }
            }
            $queryUpd = mysqli_query($conection,"UPDATE datos_empresa SET
                                                        run = '$varchNit',
                                                        nombre = '$strNombreEmp',
                                                        telefono = '$varchTelEmp',
                                                        correo = '$strEmailEmp',
                                                        direccion = '$strDirEmp',
                                                        IVA = $intIva,
                                                        logo =  '$imgEmpresa'
                                                        WHERE id = 1 ");

            mysqli_close($conection);
            if($queryUpd){
                if($nombre_foto != "")
                {
                    move_uploaded_file($url_temp,$src);//mueve la imagen
                }
                $code = '00';
                $msg = "Datos actualizados correctamente.";
              
            }else{
                $code = '2';
                $msg = "Error al actualizar los datos.";
            }

        }
        $arrData = array('cod' => $code, 'msg'=> $msg);
        echo json_encode($arrData,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
        exit;
    }
```

como puedo hacer que reconozca que se envía una imagen al ajax por java o de que manera tengo hacerlo para que funcione como se ve en la imagen por consola manda la imagen que esta C:\fakepath\download.jpg pero despues ya en ajax no la toma

[image: problema]

la verdad no se que mas colocar XD pero me pide que escriba mas por que es mucho cogido de ante mando muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

https://programacion.net/articulo/como_subir_un_fichero_a_un_formulario_mediant
e_ajax_2175 ya lo solucione mi problema con FromData

les dejo el codigo como quedo

```
$.ajax({
            url : 'ajax.php',
            type: "POST",
            async :true,
            //data: $('#frmEmpresa').serialize(),
            data: new FormData (this),
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData:false,
            beforeSend: function(){
                $('.alertFormEmpresa').slideUp();
                $('.alertFormEmpresa').html('');
                $('#frmEmpresa input').attr('disabled','disabled');
            },
            success: function(response)
            {
                console.log(response);
            }
```